# Filter IQueryable which contains (%like%) any of the items in the List<string>

Tags: c#, list, lambda, filter, iqueryable

I want to filter an IQueryable/List using List without hitting the database. The IQueryable result should include all result containing any of the strings in the List and the length of the list is unspecified.

`myQueryable = myQueryable.Where(filelist => filelist.Location.Contains(filterList[0]) || filelist.Location.Contains(filterList[1]) || filelist.Location.Contains(filterList[N])...);`

I'm using ASP.NET Core 3 and will use the IQueryable to hit the databse in a later phase using Entity Framework.

I've tried these two codes which did not work and my IQuery works fine if i exclude my trial codes (for filtering the attribute, location).

1. `workOrders = workOrders.Where(filelist => filterList.Contains(filelist.Location));   //Returns only exact match`
2. `workOrders = workOrders.Where(filelist => filterList.Any(filter => filelist.Location.ToUpperInvariant().Contains(filter.ToUpperInvariant()))); //Returns error`
3. `Expression<Func<Workorder, bool>> predicate = filelist => false;
    foreach (var filter in filterList)
     {
      Expression<Func<Workorder, bool>> orPredicate = filelist => 
      filter.Contains(filelist.Location);
      var body = Expression.Or(predicate.Body, orPredicate.Body);
      predicate = Expression.Lambda<Func<Workorder, bool>>(body, 
      predicate.Parameters[0]);
     }
    workOrders = workOrders.Where(predicate); //Returns Error`

```
class Workorder //Database Model
{
        public string SiteId { get; set; }      
        public string Location { get; set; }        
}

List<string> filterList //List to be used as filter
{
        "filterOne",
        "filterTwo",
        "filterN"          
};
```

The second code i ran gives me an error which i can get nothing out of.

System.InvalidOperationException: When called from 'VisitLambda', rewriting a node of type 'System.Linq.Expressions.ParameterExpression' must return a non-null value of the same type. Alternatively, override 'VisitLambda' and change it to not visit children of this type.

Third code i ran gives me this error,

System.InvalidOperationException: Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational.Query.Pipeline.RelationalQueryableMethodTranslatingExpressionVisitor.TranslateWhere(ShapedQueryExpression source, LambdaExpression predicate)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took me a while but i used your example to construct an expression tree that worked.

```
List<filterList> filterList //List to be used as filter
{
 "filterOne",
 "filterTwo",
 "filterN"
}

class Workorder //Database Model
{
 public string SiteId { get; set; }      
 public string Location { get; set; }        
}

static Expression<Func<T, bool>> GetExpression<T>(string propertyName, List<string> propertyValue)
{
 Expression orExpression = null;
 var parameterExp = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "type");
 var propertyExp = Expression.Property(parameterExp, propertyName);

 foreach (string searchTerm in propertyValue)
 {
  MethodInfo method = typeof(string).GetMethod("Contains", new[] { typeof(string) });
  var someValue = Expression.Constant(searchTerm, typeof(string));
  var containsMethodExp = Expression.Call(propertyExp, method, someValue);

  if(orExpression == null) //to handle intial phase when left expression = null
  {
   orExpression = Expression.Call(propertyExp, method, someValue);
  }else
  {
   orExpression = Expression.Or(orExpression, containsMethodExp);
  }
  return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(orExpression, parameterExp);
}


myQueryable = myQueryable.Where(GetExpression<Workorder>(property, filterList));
```

This Equals:

```
myQueryable = myQueryable.Where(filelist => filelist.Location.Contains(filterList[0]) || filelist.Location.Contains(filterList[1]) || filelist.Location.Contains(filterList[N])...);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have definitely not tested this... but I don't think you can do it in a one-liner if you pretend EF to parse it afterwards.

However, something like this should be fine:

```cs
Expression<Func<WorkOrder, bool>> predicate = filelist => false;
foreach(var filter in filterList) {
    Expression<Func<WorkOrder, bool>> orPredicate = filelist => filter.Contains(filelist.Location);
    var body = Expression.Or(predicate.Body, orPredicate.Body);
    predicate = Expression.Lambda<Func<WorkOrder,bool>>(body, predicate.Parameters[0]);
}
```

And then:

```cs
myQueryable = myQueryable.Where(predicate);
```

We are basically just telling it:

```
.Where(filelist => false || filterList[0].Contains(filelist.Location) || filterList[1].Contains(filelist.Location) || ...);
```

---

#### Edit

Still untested on EF, but at least the syntax seems to be ok: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Htr7Zr

Comment: Thank you for your answer but unfortunately the expression did not work with EF. You can see the error message in my updated post.

Comment: Yes, the problem is the closure (on the foreach)... you'd need to check against a constant like you did on your version